# Retrieve Unique Row

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a window that contains 3 DataWindows: dw_get, dw_lote, and dw_item.

Inside the dw_item, it will serve as rows of a table (think of it as a list of equipment). The first column contains a DDDW that works by retrieving information from the dw_lote. So far, everything is working fine.

Now, when I add a new row in the itemchanged event, it executes a Retrieve on the row with the required parameters. However, this deletes all the other rows. How can I solve this? I need to give a Retrieve to only the new row to obtain information from the other columns.

The itemchanged event retrives just the line and clears the rest.

dw_item.RetrieveStart(2) , dw_item.SetRow(dw_item.getRow()), none work. Including retrievestart, gives error: "c051: unknow function name: retrievestart"

Comment: When you retrieve you are resetting the datawindow with a new dataset based on the new retrieval.